# How to change data frame values matching specific dates in R?

Tags: r, date, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    x1= c("Station 1", "Station 1", "Station 2", "Station 3", "Station3", "Station 3")
    x2= c("02/04/92", "02/05/92", "01/14/92", "02/28/92", "03/01/92", "03/09/94")
    x3= seq(5, 30, length=6)
    x4= seq(4, 16, length=6)
    x5= c(0, -99, NA, 77, 8, 2)

    testframe = data.frame(Station=x1, Date=x2, Morning=x3, Noon=x4,Evening=x5)
```

Now I want to multiple all values for a specific date with a certain factor (for example with 3), for example all values taken between 1992-02-28 and 1994-03-09.

I did this:

```
    testframe[,2] = as.Date(testframe[,2],format="%m/%d/%y")
    testframe$Date>="1992-02-28" & testframe$Date<="1994-03-09"
```

But I dont know how to go on. I know I get the index list with the 2nd command, but I dont know how to use it to change the values in `testframe[,3:5]`?

I also know this command:

```
testframe[,3:5] * 3
```

But I want to use it only for the selected dates! How should I do it?

Comment: You were close! `foo <- testframe$Date>="1992-02-28" & testframe$Date<="1994-03-09"; testframe[foo, 3:5] <- testframe[foo, 3:5] * 3`

Comment: `testframe[testframe$Date>="1992-02-28" & testframe$Date<="1994-03-09",3:5] * 3`?

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you! It worked!